# Python - Use video received in POST request without saving it

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

I have an API which receives a video file - `funny_video` in a POST request as shown below:

```
@app.route('/myapi/version/videos', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def process_video():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        funny_video = request.files['funny_video']
```

I want to divide that video into frames and process frames individually, for which I came across two different ways to do it:

*Using **OpenCV**:*

```
vid_cap = cv2.VideoCapture("/some/file/path/funny_video.mov")
success, frame = vid_cap.read()
# .. and so on
```

*Using **PyAV**:*

```
container = av.open("/some/file/path/funny_video.mov")
for frame in container.decode(video=0):
    print('Start processing frame ..')
```

So my question is, is there any way I can pass `funny_video` to OpenCV or PyAV directly and use it or in any other way which **does not** require me to first save `funny_video` to `"/some/file/path/funny_video.mov"`?

I am using OpenCV version 2.4.9.1, PyAV version 0.3.3 and Python version 2.7.12. (Later on, will be upgrading to latest versions of Python and OpenCV, so any solutions around those versions should be OK too!)

Thanks!